# Passing Enumerables vs. Lists to a View has massive performance difference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a nutshell, I have a view which accepts:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>
```

and goes on to cycle through the model, creating a table using:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr id="tblRow_@(Model.ElementAt(i).Id)">
            <td width="1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ElementAt(i).LoggedInUser)
            </td>
            <td width="1" class="date">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ElementAt(i).DateCreated)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

So in the controller I pass `x` to the view, which is either:

```
var x = new DAL().GetList(); // returns IEnumerable<MyModel>
```

or

```
var x = new DAL().GetList().ToList();
```

Passing the 1st (IEnumerable) is waaayy slower than passing the 2nd (converted to List already)

**Why?**

I'm assuming it's something to do with Model.Count() and that maybe it has to convert the `IEnumerable` to a `List` for every cycle, but even with just 100 entries the speed difference goes from almost immediate to like, 8 seconds.

Comment: The problem I see is in two methods using IEnumerable - Count() and ElementAt(i). If it is not collection without random access optimization (SQL query or some stream-like enumerator, for example) you will execute query each time you invoke those methods. When you do ToList - you execute enumerable to the end and store result in memory.

Comment: What exactly is the thing you're passing as a model? A list exposed *as* a sequence may behave very differently from a deferred execution sequence (such as an open database query or a network query). The nature of `IEnumerable<T>` is such that it can express both scenarios.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: Use `foreach` instead. See code at the bottom.

This is mostly not about ASP.NET at all - it's the way that [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) and the extension methods on it work, in particular with respect to lazily created sequences.

When you call [`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8) on a sequence, that creates a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) by asking for each element of the original sequence - but after that, you can do everything (accessing by index, getting the count etc) without consulting the sequence at all. Not only does it not need to consult the sequence, but LINQ has optimizations for [`ElementAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8) when they're called on [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netframework-4.8) implementations.

If you call `Count()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` which doesn't implement `IList<T>` (or any of a few other interfaces that help) it has to loop through the entire sequence from the start, until it gets to the end. If the sequence is lazily evaluated (e.g. using an iterator block with `yield` statements, that means doing work again.

`ElementAt()` is similar, except it doesn't have to get to the very end - it just needs to get to the specified element.

Here's a complete console app that demonstrates the issue quite clearly - run it carefully and make sure you understand the output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var sequence = CreateSequence();
        ConsumeList(sequence);
        ConsumeSequence(sequence);
   }

    static void ConsumeList(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start of ConsumeList");
        var list = sequence.ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("ToList has completed - iterating");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            var element = list.ElementAt(i);
            Console.WriteLine($"Element {i} is {element}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End of ConsumeList");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void ConsumeSequence(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start of ConsumeSequence");
        var list = sequence.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Count(); i++)
        {
            var element = sequence.ElementAt(i);
            Console.WriteLine($"Element {i} is {element}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End of ConsumeSequence");
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> CreateSequence()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var value = i * 2;
            Console.WriteLine($"Yielding {value}");
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

This doesn't mean you need to call `ToList()` though - your whole loop can be rewritten to avoid using `Count()` and `ElementAt` entirely:

```cs
@foreach (var element in Model)
{
    <tr id="tblRow_@(element.Id)">
        <td width="1">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => element.LoggedInUser)
        </td>
        <td width="1" class="date">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => element.DateCreated)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Now the tricky part there is whether `DisplayFor` will do the right thing. It's *possible* that it won't - I don't know enough about `HtmlHelper<T>` to know exactly what's going on there. You may need to change the code a little bit more for that to work.

If you *do* need to access the element by index there, I'd change the model to a `List<T>` and use the `Count` property and the regular indexer instead:

```cs
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr id="tblRow_@(Model[i].Id)">
        <td width="1">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].LoggedInUser)
        </td>
        <td width="1" class="date">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].DateCreated)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

That way you don't have a hidden "maybe it'll be quick, maybe it won't" dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I initially had a `foreach` loop but went around a few houses trying to get DropDownLists to pass their values back to a controller, and ended up with this `int` loop. This morning I've learned my initial models weren't set up correctly and the DropDownList population is a lot easier than first thought, so I'll be refactoring and hopefully end up back at `foreach`